# QItemSelectionModel currentChange signal is emitted on application start?

Tags: qt, qt5, qmainwindow, qlistview

So I have a QMainWindow and in its constructor I do the following stuff:

```
QStringList stringList;
stringList << "aaa" << "bbb" << "ccc";
QStringListModel *list = new QStringListModel(stringList);
ui->listView->setModel(list);

stringList.append("ddd");
list->setStringList(stringList);

QObject::connect(ui->listView->selectionModel(), &QItemSelectionModel::currentChanged, [&]() {
    //do stuff
});
```

Why is the currentchanged emitted when the application starts and how can I avoid emitting the currentChanged until I actually click on the ListView?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### [What's wrong?]

Since the **listView** is the only widget in your `QMainWindow`, it will be automatically **focused** as the application starts. Once the **listView** gets focused, the first item automatically becomes the current item if there wasn't already a current item. Hence the signal emitted.

### [Solution]

#### Option 1

Add other widgets into your application and call [**`QWidget::setFocus`**](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setFocus) on one of them to make it the default focused widget as app starts.

#### Option 2

Call [**`QListView::setFocusPolicy`**](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#focusPolicy-prop) and make it [**`Qt::ClickFocus`**](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#FocusPolicy-enum), so the listView will only be focused if one of the items is clicked.

#### Option 3

The signal [**`QItemSelectionModel::currentChanged`**](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qitemselectionmodel.html#currentChanged) has actually two arguments: `QModelIndex &current` and `QModelIndex &privious`. Use them by conventional signal/slot connection. For example

```
connect(ui->listView->selectionModel(), SIGNAL(currentChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)), this, SLOT(yourSlot(QModelIndex, QModelIndex)));
```

In the slots :

```
void MainWindow::yourSlot(QModelIndex cur, QModelIndex pre)
{
    if(pre.isValid()) {
        // do stuff
    }        
}
```

P.S. `pre` being invalid signifies that there was no current item previously. This bypasses the signal emit by auto-selected for the first time the listView is focused.